# ImagesLoaded does not work with Firefox without setTimeout

Tags: javascript, firefox, imagesloaded

Any ideas why I require a timeout of at least 300ms for imagesLoaded to work on Firefox?  If I set it any less, the imagesLoaded event fires immediately before the image has loaded. I am using the latest version 3.1.x.

```
<html>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=myimage><img style="height:100px" src="http://www.worldcarwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/new-2014-audi-r8-wallpaper.jpg"/></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                var elem = $("#myimage");
                elem.imagesLoaded(function(){
                    alert("ready!!")
                });
            }, 100)
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. It seems like the images loaded triggers as the images are downloaded but firefox has some delay rendering them on the browser which causes the relayout() to use the same old height without the image. I am using the same setTimeout() to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation of this library, author use it in a different way ([here](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)).
The problem is probably when the library starts, on page load maybe, its not clear.
I don't think you should use a library for one image. You can add this in your head

```
<script>
HTMLImageElement.prototype.imageLoaded = function(callback){
    if(this.complete && this.naturalWidth>0){
        callback();
    }else{
        this.addEventListener('load', callback, false);
    }
};
</script>
```

And then on body load attach your event, like this:

```
$(function(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("myimage");
    elem.imageLoaded(function(){
        alert("ready!!")
    });
});
```

This will not work on an image load error.

Comment: This was just some a stripped down example - there will be many more images that we need to track.